# bootstrap padding from php header

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have made two columns in bootstrap, that should go beneath the header. But this 2 columns are hiding under the header. What is the correct way to make this 2 columns start beneath the header, and not start from the top of the page, where the header should be?

```
<body>

    <?php require 'header.php';?>

    <div id="container">
        <div="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 bg-warning">
                Column 1
            </div>
        </div>
        <div="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 bg-primary">
                Column 2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <?php require 'footer.php';?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you are using php to create a header but the `container` div is probably hiding beneath the header because your header has the CSS style attribute `position:fixed` or `position:absolute`. In order to solve this, assign a margin with the same height as the header. like this:

```
<body>

<?php require 'header.php';?>

<div id="container" style="margin-top: 70px"><!--INSERT THE HEIGHT OF YOUR HEADER AT THE POSITION OF THE "70"-->
    <div="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 bg-warning">
            Column 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 bg-primary">
            Column 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<?php require 'footer.php';?> </body>
```

Cheers,

Comment: thank you a lot. If I want to set a height on the columns, is it correct to set fx a height: 400px; or should the content of the columns control the heights?

Comment: It is not incorrect to set a height on a column in bootstrap?

Comment: No, it isn't. You would just override the standard height

Comment: Ps. If your question has been answered, please mark as 'Correct Answer',

Answer (score 0):

Also drop the second row. It's not needed.

```
<div id="container">
   <div="row">
       <div class="col-lg-6 bg-warning">
        Column 1
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 bg-primary">
        Column 2
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```